# Once query by PDO for get known field values?

Tags: php, pdo

my settings table have setsactive(field) with 2 known value: 0 or 1

how by one query for field setsactive get:
count rows with value "0" and count rows with value "1"

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT setsid, setsname, setsactive, setstype
FROM settings WHERE setsactive = ?');
$setsactive = 0;
$stmt->bindValue(':setsactive', $setsactive, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();   
echo $rows_set_active = $stmt->rowCount();
$setsactive1 = 1;
$stmt->bindValue(':setsactive', $setsactive1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();   
echo $rows_set_deactive = $stmt->rowCount();
```

thanks

**Updated > remove second query**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT
    setsactive,
    COUNT(1) AS totalCount
FROM settings
GROUP BY setsactive
```

---

or

```sql
SELECT
    setsactive,
    SUM( IF(setsactive = 1, 1, 0) ) AS activeCount,
    SUM( IF(setsactive = 0, 1, 0) ) AS deactiveCount
FROM settings
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT setsactive, count(*) cnt FROM settings GROUP BY setsactive
```

And **NO** - if you insists on the **totally wrong** way of getting count - you CAN'T run these two WRONG queries in one call. Satisfied?

Comment: **thanks** based on your answer i removed second query; now please help me by PDO syntax